# Why is VisualStudio looking for this lib file? LNK1104 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker

We have a large project using VS2008 and boost 1_42.  I'm trying to upgrade to VS2010 and boost 1_44.  I installed VS2010 and boost 1_44 and converted the project.  Now I am trying to build, and everything compiles, but fails when linking:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_42.lib'`

I have changed the include and lib directories to point to the new boost 1_44 files and I have renamed the old boost 1_42 directory.

Why is the linker still looking for a vc90-1_42 file, when it is only using 1_44 headers?  Is there a way that I can determine WHY the linker wants this file?  The linker obviously thinks it needs the file, but why?

I have cleaned the project and I am re-building to ensure any old build files are erased.

Comment: OK, so I found out what my problem was, but I would still like an answer to "How can I find out why the linker wants this file?".  My project was dependent on one of our lib files that was built using boost 1_42.  I recompiled the lib file with boost 1_44, and the linker error on the main project went away.  Is there some log or utility I could have used to see that was happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. This kind of information ("need to link to some_lib") is probably buried deep inside generated obj and lib files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Along with changing the lib directory, you need to change the name of the boost library. That's in the Linker | Input section of the project settings.</strike>

Your added comment makes it clear that the dependency on the Boost 1.42 library was being created indirectly by another library that hadn't been rebuilt.

For this you basically have two choices: either add that library as a project to your main solution, and make sure it has enough dependency information that it'll be re-built when you upgrade Boost, or use the [`/Zl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) compiler switch when you build your library. This tells the compiler you're building a library so you do *not* want to embed library dependencies like this.

Comment: Boost uses auto-linking, so I do not manually list all of the files in the Linker|Input section.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into exactly this problem a couple of times too. It's usually been some old temporary files but like in your case cleaning didn't always do the trick straight away. Does your project include any static libs that might have been built with 1.42?

Something you can try which may or may not be helpful in tracking down your issue:
Rename the old boost directory back to it's original name

- Clean the solution
- Under C/C++->Command Line->Additional Options add "/showIncludes"
- Under Linker->Command Line->Additional Options add "/verbose:lib"
- Rebuild all

Then when you build you'll be able to see at which point 1.42 headers are included, etc. in the output window. Somehow doing this helped me in tracking down where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Boost uses

```
#pragma comment(lib)
```

command to inform the linker of libraries it needs to link with. It is not an error. If Boost says you need it, it's likely you do.

Comment: I'm saying it's an error because there is no reason boost 1_44 would need a boost 1_42 lib file.

Comment: There might be a bug in Boost then, but i doubt it.

Comment: I believe Jerry Coffin's right. You probably have a dependency on some other library (home made or not) that depends on boost 1.42. Hence the auto-linking issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes, but the real question is how can I see those dependencies?  How can I determine WHY the linker wants that file if I have no other information to go on...

Answer (score 1):

**On How can I find out why the linker wants this file?**

There are programs which will go through your app and dlls/libs and report the content of manifests and what the binaries report they depend on.  You could then scan the report for the unexpected libraries being included.  We used this mainly to find libs including the previous version of the VC runtime.

Have not used the one we had in about 5 years though, now if only I could remember the name of the app!

DependancyWalker (depends.exe) will allow you to see dependancies of dll/exe but not static libs.

You could open each binary as a 'file' in MSVS and look at the manifest content by hand, but I imaging this would be a bit painful.  I've not tried this with a static lib.